# how to add sequence to primary key in plSQL

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm using pl sql developer 12.what i want is to add the make the primary key sequential using oracle 12' windows and forms , not by scripting. I can't find out how?.
 aslo, how can i make one to one relation between 2 tables (user,role), in user table i added role_id as foreign key; but the relation seem one to many!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I have done lastly is that i downloaded sql developer 64 w, and from it; I connected with the database then I made the column sequential

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c and above, you define that column as `identity` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  -- other columns ... 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A @Mureinik already said, in Oracle 12 and higher versions you can define your primary key column as `NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` to get a unique sequential value.

To enforce a one-to-one relationship in the database you'd want to have your `ROLE_ID` column defined as a primary key on one table, and as either a UNIQUE or PRIMARY key on the second table, with a foreign key relationship between the tables. In other words:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ROLE_ID  NUMBER
                   CONSTRAINT PK_T1
                     PRIMARY KEY
                 ...);

CREATE TABLE T2 (ID_T2    NUMBER
                   PRIMARY KEY,
                 ROLE_ID  NUMBER
                   CONSTRAINT T2_U1
                     UNIQUE
                   CONSTRAINT T2_FK1
                     REFERENCES T1(ROLE_ID)
                       ON DELETE CASCADE,
                 ...);
```

After the above `ROLE_ID` will be the primary key on T1, a unique key on T2, and T2.ROLE_ID will be a foreign key to T1.

Best of luck.